# Mongoengine filtering on a listField with __contains not working

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I have a field in my document place_names which is a list of all possible place names for a location. Example New York City with have New York City, NYC, big apple etc.
I want the user to be able to query on any of these values or any part of the above values.
For example if they search for "apple" i want them to get New York City back. I was trying to use the __contains filter in mongoengine as below

place_names is of type ListField()

```
pn = request.POST.get('place_name', None)

try:
    places_list = Places.objects()
    if pn is not None and pn != "":
        places_list.filter(place_names__contains = pn)
```

In the above example the filter doesn't work the way I expect it to. It works as a regular filter and doesn't do the "_*contains". The same filter works fine if the type is StringField(). Is it possible to use "*_contains" with ListFields? If not is there any way around this? thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__contains` is a string lookup using a regex under the hood.  To check if an item is in a listfield you should use the `__in` however, that does an exact match.

You could denormalise and create a `ListField` with the place names split into single words and lowercased, then you can use `__in` to determine if there is a match.

Comment: Thanks saved me a lot of frustration. Disappointed that you can't do a __contains on a listField. Oh well

Comment: Currently there is no full text search in mongoDB - you can read up on approaches here - http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Full+Text+Search+in+Mongo Once Full text is implemented in core mongoDB then we'd be able to achieve what you want.  Could you mark the question as answered for others looking at this in the future